# Homotopy product

Tags: homotopy-theory, model-categories

Sorry if this is a trivial question.

Let $ \mathfrak{X} $ be a model category such that all objects of $ \mathfrak{X} $ are fibrant. Then we have a total derived functor of the product 
$ \mathfrak{X}\times\mathfrak{X}\to\mathfrak{X} $,
because, in this case, by the Ken Brown's Lemma, the product functor preserves weak equivalences.

However, I wonder if there are conditions which assure that the product reflects weak equivalences.

Thank you in advance

Comment: It's false in some of the most important model categories: $\mathbf{Set}$, $\mathbf{Cat}$, $\mathbf{sSet}$. Note that the first two have the property that every object is fibrant, and all three have the property that binary products preserve weak equivalences.

Comment: @ZhenLin , thank you for the comment. When you say $Set$, are you talking about the trivial model structure in $ Set $? 
If $f\times g $ is a bijection, then $ f $ and $g$ are bijections. Am I mistaken?
I might be wrong. But it seems that the product in Set reflects isomorphisms.
I would say the same for products of categories and equivalences...
Please, correct me.

Comment: In every case, $\emptyset$ provides the counterexample.

Comment: @ZhenLin , Oh! You are right! Thank you.
But, in $Cat$ and $Set$, the products reflects all isomorphisms but the $\emptyset\to\emptyset $. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right.